# Vector valued line integral

Tags: real-analysis, vector-analysis, distribution-theory

I am confronted by a line integral of the form

$$ \pmb{A}_C(\pmb{x}) = \int_{\pmb{x_1}}^{\pmb{x_2}} \delta^3(\pmb{x}-\pmb{z}) \; d\pmb{z}, $$

where $C$ is a path between two points $\pmb{x_1}$ and $\pmb{x_2}$, and the $\pmb{x}$-dependence of the result is ensured by the 3D Dirac delta distribution.

So this object to me is quite confusing, I can't find either a nice intuitive way nor a methodological way to do anything with this integral. Logically I tried to examine this object with taking $C$ to be the straight line, meaning that the path is given by

$$\pmb{z}(t) = \pmb{x_1} + t (\pmb{x_2}-\pmb{x_1}), $$

but I am a bit puzzled on how to actually use this path parametrization in the integral itself. The  way I've learnt to do line integrals is $\int_c \pmb{A}(\pmb{r}) \; d\pmb{z} = \int_{t_0}^{t_1} \pmb{A}(\pmb{r}(t)) \cdot \pmb{z}'(t) \; dt $, but I am confused how to actually do this with a Dirac delta distribution. To remove this difficulty I've also tried to do Fourier transformation to get

$$ \pmb{A}_C(\pmb{x}) = \int_{\pmb{x_1}}^{\pmb{x_2}} \delta^3(\pmb{x}-\pmb{z}) \; d\pmb{z}, = \int_{\pmb{x_1}}^{\pmb{x_2}} e^{i \pmb{k} \pmb{z}} \; d\pmb{z},$$

but I still can't really see how could I adapt my path here. I guess the thing that's confusing me is that usually I take the path integral of a vector field and get a scalar, but here I essentially take the path integral of a scalar field to get a vector field. I also understand that the result should still be a distribution, as in the only thing that will be a 'normal' function is $\int \pmb{A}_C(\pmb{x}) f(x) \; dx$, but I still want to have some insight into the mathematical meaning of the distribution formula as well as how exactly to calculate with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading a paper where the formula appears, I now understand better. I find it easier to construct the integral than to interpret it, so let me take it that way.

Let $C$ be a smooth directed curve in $\mathbb{R}^3.$ In the papers they want to construct a field $\mathbf A_C$ that lives only on $C$ and has the direction of $C$. I will do this by splitting the curve into line segments. So let $\mathbf x_0, \mathbf x_1, \ldots, \mathbf x_n$ be ordered points on the curve, with $\mathbf x_0$ being the start point of $C$ and $\mathbf x_n$ being the end point.

Below I will show that the field living on the line segment from $\mathbf x_k$ to $\mathbf x_{k+1}$ can be expressed as
$$
\mathbf A_{\mathbf x_k, \mathbf x_{k+1}}(\mathbf x)
= -\int_{\mathbf x_k}^{\mathbf x_{k+1}} \delta^3(\mathbf x-\mathbf x') \, d\mathbf x'
.
$$
The field along the polygonal chain $\mathbf x_0,\ldots,\mathbf x_n$ then is
$$
\mathbf A_{\mathbf x_0,\ldots,\mathbf x_n}(\mathbf x)
= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \mathbf A_{\mathbf x_k, \mathbf x_{k+1}}(\mathbf x)
= -\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \int_{\mathbf x_k}^{\mathbf x_{k+1}} \delta^3(\mathbf x-\mathbf x') \, d\mathbf x'
.
$$
Taking limits by refining the segmentation of $C$ we arrive at
$$
\mathbf A_C(\mathbf x) = -\int_C \delta^3(\mathbf x-\mathbf x') \, d\mathbf x'
.
$$

Now to the field along a line segment. First we consider a line segment parallel to the $x$-axis, from point $\mathbf x_0=(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ to point $\mathbf x_1=(x_1,y_0,z_0).$ The field on this can be expressed as
$$
\mathbf A_{\mathbf x_0, \mathbf x_1}(x,y,z)
= 1_{[x_0,x_1]}(x) \delta(y-y_0) \delta(z-z_0) \, \mathbf e_x,
$$
where $\mathbf e_x$ is the unit vector in the $x$ direction and $1_{[x_0,x_1]}$ is the indicator function on the interval $[x_0,x_1]$ (in one dimension).

Now we can write $1_{[x_0,x_1]}(x)$ as an integral:
$$
1_{[x_0,x_1]}(x)
= H(x-x_0) - H(x-x_1)
= -\int_{x_0}^{x_1} \delta(x-x') \, dx'
.
$$

Inserting this into the expression for $\mathbf A_{\mathbf x_0,\mathbf x_1}(\mathbf x)$ gives
$$\begin{align}
\mathbf A_{(x_0,y_0,z_0), (x_1,y_0,z_0)}(x,y,z)
&= \left(-\int_{x_0}^{x_1} \delta(x-x') \, dx'\right) \, \delta(y-y_0) \delta(z-z_0) \, \mathbf e_x \\
&= -\int_{x_0}^{x_1} \delta(x-x') \delta(y-y_0) \delta(z-z_0) \, \mathbf e_x \, dx' \\
&= -\int_{(x_0,y_0,z_0)}^{(x_1,y_0,z_0)} \delta(x-x') \delta(y-y') \delta(z-z') \, (\mathbf e_x\,dx'+\mathbf e_y\,dy'+\mathbf e_z\,dz') \\
&= -\int_{\mathbf x_0}^{\mathbf x_1} \delta^3(\mathbf x - \mathbf x') \, d\mathbf x', \\
\end{align}$$
where it has been used that $y=y_0$, $z=z_0$ and $dy=dz=0$ along the line segment.

Since the last expression is inherently independent of direction of the line segment, we conclude that the field living on the line segment from $\mathbf x_k$ to $\mathbf x_{k+1}$ can be expressed as
$$
\mathbf A_{\mathbf x_k, \mathbf x_{k+1}}(\mathbf x)
= -\int_{\mathbf x_k}^{\mathbf x_{k+1}} \delta^3(\mathbf x-\mathbf x') \, d\mathbf x'
.
$$

---

**My first interpretation**

This is my interpretation:
$$
\mathbf{A}_C(\mathbf{x}) = \int_{\mathbf{x_1}}^{\mathbf{x_2}} \delta^3(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{z}) \, d\mathbf{z}
= \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \mathbf{1}_C(\mathbf z)\,\delta^3(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{z})\,d\mathbf{z}
= \mathbf{1}_C(\mathbf x)
= \begin{cases}
1 & \text{if $\mathbf x\in C$} \\
0 & \text{if $\mathbf x\not\in C$} \\
\end{cases}
$$

Here, $\mathbf{1}_C$ is the indicator function of $C$.

Comment: This sounds somewhat reasonable. I think if I only consider the 1D case I can also convince myself that I get the step function (which should be the 1D analogue of the indicator function). Two things are not totally clear still: the result has to be a vector valued indicator function, right? So it's not $1$ or $0$, but I guess $\pmb{\hat{e}}_r$ and $0$ or something. Also: how do you integrate against the indicator function? What would be, for example, $\int e^{-x} \pmb{1}_c(\pmb{x}) \; d\pmb{x}$, as in, an integral of a simple exp. decay? With Dirac delta it's easy, with this I don't see it.

Comment: @LaBelleCroissant. I cannot see why the right hand side of $\pmb{A}_C(\pmb{x}) = \int_{\pmb{x_1}}^{\pmb{x_2}} \delta^3(\pmb{x}-\pmb{z}) \; d\pmb{z},$ would be a vector. When one writes $\delta^3$ what is normally meant is $\delta\otimes\delta\otimes\delta,$ i.e. $\delta^3(x,y,z)=\delta(x)\delta(y)\delta(z),$ a product of three scalar-valued distributions.

Comment: I think my confusion is partly from the fact that my background is in physics, and here we usually consider line integrals of the form $\int \pmb{A}(\pmb{x}) \; d \pmb{z}$ or $\int f(\pmb{x}) \; d l$, that is I either integrate a scalar field against a scalar line element (giving a scalar), or I integrate a vector field against a vector displacement element (giving a scalar again). Here I think I need to integrate the scalar field of the Dirac delta against a displacement element, giving me a vector field as a result I suppose.

Comment: @LaBelleCroissant. Don't you mean $\int \pmb{A}(\pmb{x}) \cdot \; d \pmb{z}$? I also have a background in physics, plus mathematics and computer science.

Comment: Additional comment: I've encountered this object in the context of electrodnynamics, where some authors suggest the distribution $\int_C \delta^3(\pmb{x}-\pmb{z}) \; d \pmb{z}$ as a vector field that, when taken the divergence of, gives $\delta^3(\pmb{x_1}-{x})$ with $\pmb{x_1}$ being one of the endpoints of $C$. This is what I've tried to adapt in my question as I have problems understanding the meaning of this object. But since I know that we take the divergence of this thing, it should really be a vector field.

Comment: @LaBelleCroissant. So it should perhaps be interpreted as
$$\left( \int_C \delta(x_1-z_1) \delta(x_2-z_2) \delta(x_3-z_3) \, dz_1, \cdots dz_2, \cdots dz_3 \right)$$
With $\cdots$ I here mean the same integral up to the differential.

Comment: That's probably correct, but then how do you interpret it as an indicator function? Do I take a 'vector', that has the range of $C$ on each axis in the components?

Comment: I understand your confusion now. I'm really confused, too.

Comment: Do you know whether the expression appears in "Classical Electrodynamics" 2nd Ed. by J. D. Jackson?

Comment: I don't think Jackson is concerned with this object as it is mostly in the context of QED. Here's a paper from last year where it appears: https://journals.aps.org/prresearch/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevResearch.2.013206 . The relevant discussions are either around Eqs. 13-14 or Eqs. 40-45 (I took the straight path idea in my question from there).

Comment: I also found it as eq. (50) in [ArXiv/1801.07735](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.07735.pdf).

Comment: After reading the contexts in the papers I now understand better and am trying to write down an explanation.

Comment: @LaBelleCroissant. I have now updated my post.